# A different value is inserted in my array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I have a variable called 'end' and is inserting value inside my 2d array called 'xWithSurface'. Everything works perfectly until it reaches [1][8], [1][9], [2][6] and some location.

These are indices with problems: (Some location even contain values that is not an interval of 6)

With Surface: X1[1][0]: 0  X2[1][1]: 6    Y[1]: 1

With Surface: X1[1][2]: 6   X2[1][3]: 12    Y[1]: 1

With Surface: X1[1][4]: -1   X2[1][5]: -1    Y[1]: 1

With Surface: X1[1][6]: 18   X2[1][7]: 1    Y[1]: 1

With Surface: X1[1][8]: 2   X2[1][9]: 3    Y[1]: 1 <<<<<<-------

.

With Surface: X1[2][0]: 4   X2[2][1]: 5    Y[2]: 2 <<<<-----

With Surface: X1[2][2]: 6   X2[2][3]: 7    Y[2]: 2 <<<<<<-----

With Surface: X1[2][4]: 8   X2[2][5]: 9    Y[2]: 2

With Surface: X1[2][6]: 1   X2[2][7]: 24    Y[2]: 2

With Surface: X1[2][8]: -1   X2[2][9]: -1    Y[2]: 2

Other indices are perfectly okay

Here is my code:

```
srand(time(0));

int xWithSurface[][10] = {};
int yWithSurface[10] = {};

int y;
int x;
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

    int start = 0;
    int end = 6;

    for (x = 0; x < 10; x+=2) {

        int surface = (rand()%2);

        if (surface == 1){
            xWithSurface[y][x] = start;
            xWithSurface[y][x+1] = end;
            yWithSurface[y] = y;

            printf("^^^^^^^");

        } else if (surface == 0) {
            xWithSurface[y][x] = -1;
            xWithSurface[y][x+1] = -1;
            yWithSurface[y] = y;

            printf("       ");
        }

        start += 6;
        end += 6;
    }

    printf("\n");   

}
```

}

How I print my arrary:

```
 int o, p;
 for (o = 0; o < 10; o++) {
   for (p = 0; p < 10; p+=2){   
        printf("With Surface: X1[%d][%d]: %d   X2[%d][%d]: %d    Y[%d]: %d ", o, p, xWithSurface[o][p], o, p+1, xWithSurface[o][p+1], o, yWithSurface[o]);
        printf("\n");
     }
    printf("\n\n");
 }
```

Comment: No images please. Also, please fix a [mre]

Comment: `int xWithSurface[][10] = {};` declares next to nothing (at least nothing particularly usable).

Comment: How do you print your array ? It may be a print problem and not a filling problem

Comment: I have fixed and tidied my code a bit, i'm new here sorry

Comment: It's not a [mre]. For instance, there's no main function.

Comment: Since WhozCraig gives an obscure hint, here's another one: `printf("xWithSurface is just %zd bytes long\n", sizeof xWithSurface);`.

Comment: OMG I never thought 2d array initialization really requires both dimensions, was it java that is fine with it?... Anyways, thank you so much!

Comment: How do you upvote or indicate that it's solved?